# Razor formatting off on older code files in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: blazor-server-side, visual-studio-mac, .net-5

Under a single solution, I converted .net 3.1 Blazor server project to .net 5. Also, created new .net 5 Blazor server project.

In the newer projects VS-Mac formats .razor documents perfectly, while the formatting of the documents in the older, converted projects is all out of wack.

I've tried really hard to find the reason why the newer files are OK, but the older files aren't to no avail.

Does anyone have any clue how to make the older files format like the newer ones?

I know there's an experimental code editor for razor files, but it seems to be available only for VS for windows.

Thanks

-- Added a portion of a large .razor component file after doing a document format. You'll appreciate the mess. Further down the file it's worse.

For one, the closing brackets "}" are being misplaced.
HTMKL elements aren't indented.

[image]

Comment: Please show examples of "out of wack" and what your are expecting.

Comment: Added a portion of an out-of-wack-file.

Comment: cmd-a then ctrl-i do anything?

Comment: cmd-a, ctrl-i doesn't do much. It moves a couple of end brackets down one row. If I do it a second time, the moved bracket goes back to the end of the previous row.

Comment: Does your page/app execute ok?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Occasionally, UI will break because I'll end up placing some HTML in the wrong place because of the awkward formatting.

Comment: This behavior happens only on older projects in the solution. If I create a new project within the solution, the formatting is OK. I don't understand it. The only thing I can think of is that there must be some file somewhere with a setting that ties a specific project to a specific version of a formatter. I've even gone as far as completely removing VS-Mac from my machine and reinstalling it. And, it also happens when I open the sol in VS-Windows.

Comment: Everything default here: Preferences -> Source Code -> Code Formatting -> HTML?

Comment: All code formatting setting are set to Default. The older projects were all using .Net Core 3.1 before I migrated them to .Net 5. Newer projects referenced .Net 5 from the start. Nevertheless, the formatting problem was already happening present when older projects were referencing .Net 3.1. I waste an enormous amount of time reformatting the files or figuring out where the end of code blocks are. And VS-Mac does not allow one to turn off automatic formatting.

Comment: I use VS-Mac because I do most of my work on Mac. I have Fusion VM w Windows 10, but I found it hard to deal with the different key mappings. I switched from VS-Windows about a year ago, and it all was working well until, a few months ago, after a VS-Mac update. VS-Code isn't any better, btw. It also does funky stuff to .razor files. BTW, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Yea, sorry I wasnt much help, I'm at a loss on what to do next.

Comment: One last comment, @mxmissile. Based on this video I watched yesterday (https://youtu.be/_znjce8Cs2k) I removed all the code in the .razor file, saved it in another editor (VS-Code), then proceeded to take small pieces of the saved code and pasting back to the original file in VS-Mac. That did not work. The formatting did not improve. Then, I again erased the code I had pasted in, saved the empty file, and typed in the first if statement and voila, the formatting of that code block was perfect. I again tried to paste in portions of the VS-Code file and that worked. Unbelievable...

Comment: Finally, I pasted the entire rest of the code, and although the formatting was OK, I noticed that the closing brackets were not as I preferred them, in a separate line, so I found each one, deleted it, hit the enter key, and typed them each on there own line. Now everything is cool.

Comment: Sounds like a whitespace issue between the mac and windows.